# Creating a thread in android not working

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I have a method that I'm calling but, for newer versions of Android it fails. Apparently, this is due to the lack of threading. My method is to send a message to my server. This is the code (sans threading)

```
public String sendMessage(String username, Editable message){
        BufferedReader in = null;
        String data = null;

        try{
            DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            URI website = new URI("http://abc.com/user_send.php?username="+username+"&message="+message);

            HttpPost post_request = new HttpPost();
            post_request.setURI(website);


            HttpGet request = new HttpGet();

            request.setURI(website);
            //executing actual request
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
            String l = "";
            String nl = System.getProperty("line.separator");
            while ((l = in.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(l);

            }
            in.close();
            data = sb.toString();
            return data;
        }catch (Exception e){
            return "ERROR";
        }
    }
```

**Now, just trying to put a thread around it:**

```
    public String sendMessage(String username, Editable message){
        BufferedReader in = null;
        String data = null;
Thread sendThread = new Thread(){
        try{
            DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            URI website = new URI("http://thenjtechguy.com/njit/gds/user_send.php?username="+username+"&message="+message);

            HttpPost post_request = new HttpPost();
            post_request.setURI(website);


            HttpGet request = new HttpGet();

            request.setURI(website);
            //executing actual request
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
            String l = "";
            String nl = System.getProperty("line.separator");
            while ((l = in.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(l);

            }
            in.close();
            data = sb.toString();
            return data;
        }catch (Exception e){
            return "ERROR";
        }
} sendThread.start();   
}
```

But that doesn't work. What am I doing wrong? Also, if you notice I'm breaking any fundamental rules in android regarding the HttpClient, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better to a head and use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) concept.

AsyncTask enables proper and easy use of the UI thread. This class allows to perform background operations and publish results on the UI thread without having to manipulate threads and/or handlers.
Refer this [LINK](http://androidpartaker.wordpress.com/2010/08/01/android-async-task/) for sample implementation

Answer (score 2):

Your implementation is not correct - you did not override run() method

```
class SendThread extends Thread {
   public void run(){
        //add your implementation here
   }
}
```

Tow start the thread

```
SendThread sendThread  = new SendThread();
sendThread.start();
```

Comment: Hmm... I tried running it but, I get an error on a bracket. I don't think I'm using your answer correctly. Sorry, I'm still very new to programming.

Comment: It says Fatal Exception: 04-23 00:30:18.234: E/AndroidRuntime(29500): java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

Comment: Which line are you getting exception on?

Comment: Right before the fatal exception. I have this error: 04-23 11:54:44.572: W/dalvikvm(5981): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a451f8)

Comment: I am sure he is trying to implement and running thread while doing on Main UI Thread.